# General: Doing a LEFT JOIN on a string in SQL

Tags: sql, string, join, left-join, varchar

I have 2 tables, both have a patient identifier that is a string (combo of numbers and letters).
Is there a way to join the 2 tables on the patient identifier? Or do I need to have an int patient identifier to join the two tables?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? Please give some sample data/structure. I think most RDBMS supports joining on string/char/varchar columns, so you just need to ```FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.patientId=tbl2.patientId```

Comment: You should try to do the join on your DB. This will be easy and quick to know if it works. If you have problem with your SQL query, edit and put it in your question so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can join on *any* boolean expression in any database that supports SQL.  The expression does not even need to be equality -- although equi-joins tend to perform much, much better than other types of joins.

You can definitely join on strings and the query will be reasonably efficient.

Integers are preferred in general for practical reasons:

- They tend to be smaller (4 bytes) so they are more efficient when repeated in multiple tables.
- They are fixed length which makes indexes slightly more efficient (although patient ids might be also have a fixed length as well).
- Strings might have issues with uppercase/lowercase and collation.
- Strings might have issues with privacy.

The last issue may be the most important in your database.  You might want to consider if you want an internal id that hides the actual patient number.

However, from the SQL perspective it is perfectly fine to use a string as a primary key, foreign key, and for joining.